validation rule formula on picklist field value which have symbols(-,())
Criteria: when i create a record if picklist field value is ABC 99 - PAQ (XYZ) ,  closed date field should not be empty. i tried below formula but getting syntax error at ") . do  i need add any thing to cover ( & ) brackets ?
AND(
    ISBLANK(Closed_Date__c),
    ISPICKVAL(Issue_Template_Selection__c, "ABC 99 - PAQ (XYZ)")
)

solution:
it works with single quote as per  @Tushar Jadav suggestions.
AND(
ISBLANK(Closed_Date__c),
ISPICKVAL(Issue_Template_Selection__c, 'ABC 99 - PAQ (XYZ)'))


Sanity Check: Are you sure you're using double quotes and not accidentally using "smart" quotes?

The issue might be with the quotation marks around your picklist value. Try using single quotes instead of double quotes for the picklist value.
AND( ISBLANK(Closed_Date__c), ISPICKVAL(Issue_Template_Selection__c, 'ABC 99 - PAQ (XYZ)') ) 

@TusharJadav I'm fairly sure that formulas can use either single or double quotes.

Thank you @TusharJadav, it works with single quotes.

@TusharJadav or you, sdandamud1 should make an answer.

The issue might be with the quotation marks around your picklist value.
Try using single quotes instead of double quotes for the picklist value.
AND( 
   ISBLANK(Closed_Date__c), 
   ISPICKVAL(Issue_Template_Selection__c, 'ABC 99 - PAQ (XYZ)') 
)


solution:
it works with single quote as per @Tushar Jadav suggestions.
AND(
ISBLANK(Closed_Date__c),
ISPICKVAL(Issue_Template_Selection__c, 'ABC 99 - PAQ (XYZ)'))

